# Script in a pod is not getting executed

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster and an RDS (mariadb). I am trying to make a backup of given databases though a script in a `CronJob`. The `CronJob` object looks like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: mysqldump
  namespace: mysqldump
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Replace
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: mysql-backup
            image: viejo/debian-mysqldump:latest
            envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: mysqldump-config
            args:
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
            - /root/mysqldump.sh "(${MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES})" > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2 || echo KO > /tmp/healthcheck
            resources:
              limits:
                cpu: "0.5"
                memory: "0.5Gi"
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

The script is called `mysqldump.sh`, which gets all necessary details from a `ConfigMap` object. It makes the dump of the databases in an environment variable `MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES`, and moves it to S3 bucket.

*Note: I am going to move some variables to a `Secret`, but before I need this to work.*

What happens is NOTHING. The script is never getting executed I tried putting a "echo starting the backup", before the script, and "echo backup ended" after it, but I don't see none of them. If I'd access the container and execute the same exact command manually, it works:

```
root@mysqldump-27550908-sjwfm:/# /root/mysqldump.sh "(${MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES})" > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2 || echo KO > /tmp/healthcheck
root@mysqldump-27550908-sjwfm:/#
```

[image]

Can anyone point out a possible issue?

Comment: i have a similar issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try change `args` to `command`:

```
...
command:
- /bin/bash
- -c
- /root/mysqldump.sh "(${MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES})" > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2 || echo KO > /tmp/healthcheck
...
```